# Add class or id to video tag when it starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html5-video

I want to add a class if there is **no** class when I started the video first time.

I want to give a video element a class or id. The Name is not so important. When i start the Video the class/id shall be set. Then i can interact with the element and extract the source.

From **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7FhU/1/)**:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("video").className += " MyClass";
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

    var video = document.getElementById(inputs[i].id);

    video.onplaying = function (e) {
        /*Do things here!*/
        alert(this.src);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/E7FhU/6/)

```
(function () {
   var video = document.getElementById("myVID");
    video.addEventListener('play', function (e) {
    if (this.className.indexOf('MyClass') == -1)
       this.className += " MyClass";
    });
})();
```

**Update**
*as per comments, if there is only one video element without `id` or `class` you can access it using `document.getElementsByTagName` as follows:*

```
(function () {
   var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    video.addEventListener('play', function (e) {
    if (this.className.indexOf('MyClass') == -1)
       this.className += " MyClass";
    });
})();
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/E7FhU/7/)

Comment: But my Problem is that i have no class or id. So i want to set a class by starting the video.

Comment: This is not mentioned in your question. please update your question properly. what kind of class/ id do you want to set? something random?

Comment: Thank you for your solution but the prpblem is still there. I need a Code which alerts me when i clicked a video element. But the Video Element has **no class and no id**.

Comment: Only one! Like my sample.